# Mistake In an Email to Professor that is already sent out

Tags: email

I wrote an cold email to a professor to inquire about research opportunity. But I made an unforgivable mistake that I wrote his institution name wrong in the text. I should have wrote 'your research group in [institution A]',  but I somehow subconsciously wrote [institution B]. This is going to make him feel that I am cold emailing a couple of professors which is indeed what I am doing(but I am not writing generic emails), and this error escaped my three time re-examination. 
How should I compose my follow-up email to correct this or is there anything else I can do?? Thanks guys. Cold emailing professor is already making me feel weird.

Comment: See the answer below.  It is normal to enquire about position at two or more places. So don't worry too much.

Comment: @Alchimista Thanks, you make me feel relieved a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way I see it, you have two choices:

1. Do nothing - I do not endorse this, as it transmits the message that you do not care, or even worse, you did it on purpose;
2. Send another e-mail with the proper apologies (do not over-do it), and correct the mistake.

The message can be as simple as:

> Dear ....
>
> In previous e-mail I wrote: "...ABC..." while I intended to write "...XYZ...". Please accept my apologies, this was totally unintended. I cannot even explain it to myself.
>
> Yours...

Words may vary.

Comment: +1, but for option #2, I would be even more concise (1 line), something like: "Sorry for the typo, of course you are at [institution]."

Comment: @cag51: Usually I go for the "short and clear" too. In this particular case (and others similar), I think it is not a very good idea to be "in a hurry" - the professor might fell under-valued by the "student". Otherwise, +1

Comment: Yeah...in my imagination, the original e-mail was already far too wordy (they usually are) and so sending _another_ formal e-mail (even a brief one) is really digging the hole deeper, whereas a one-liner probably wouldn't do any harm. But maybe that is an unjust assumption about the original e-mail.

Comment: I feel you. Extremes are never good. It may not be possible to fix an email which is too long, with another one which is too short. Joke: Depending on font size, almost any e-mail can be a one-liner :D